# Writing equations within dgroup environment

Tags: equations, breqn

I am having a problem with writing equations using `dmath` and `dgroup` in my article. the  packages I am using are

```
\documentclass[a4paper 12pt] {article}
\usepackage{breqn}
```

The codes I am writing are -

```
\begin{dgroup}
\begin{dmath}
v_f = k_f C_O(0,t) = \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
v_b = k_b C_R(0,t) = \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\label{eq14}
\end{dgroup}
```

The problem is that it has two equal signs in the same line of equation. with this settings I am getting the results okay but after the two lines of equations, LaTeX puts a big gap before I start my text again. When I use `equation` in place of `dmath`, the big space after the two lines of equations are gone but the equations are not at two lines any more. It puts the `= \frac{i_c}{nFA}` part into the next line, which I don't want. Can anyone please help me with a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) illustrates the problem as I can't seem to reproduce the behavior your describe.  I thought the problem was that you were leaving a blank line after the display math, but even that does not seem to result in additional vertical space.  Usually showing the problem is better than describing it.

Comment: Write `\hiderel{=}` for the equal signs that shouldn't mark an alignment point. I contend that `\begin{align}A&=B=C\\D&=E=F\end{align}` is easier to write, read and maintain.

Comment: Hi egreg, Thanks that actually works with the \dmath.

Answer (score 5):

A relation symbol that shouldn't be considered an alignment point in `dmath` should be marked with `\hiderel`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dgroup}
\begin{dmath}
v_f = k_f C_O(0,t) \hiderel{=} \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
v_b = k_b C_R(0,t) \hiderel{=} \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\label{eq14}
\end{dgroup}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I really can't see much advantage than writing

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq14}
\begin{align}
v_f &= k_f C_O(0,t) = \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\\
v_b &= k_b C_R(0,t) \hiderel{=} \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats even better. Thats very much

Answer (score 3):

It's always worth posting complete documents. The space after a display depends on lots of things in the example below it is slightly larger gap to line 2 after the `breqn` layout than to line 7 after the `equation` layout., but not really noticeably so, but perhaps you were comparing to the gap before line 4 with two consecutive equations, that is noticeably less as the `\belowdisplayshortskip` is used in that case (which is 6pt rather than 10pt here).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\showoutput
\begin{document}

1Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
\begin{dgroup}
\begin{dmath}
v_f = k_f C_O(0,t) = \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\begin{dmath}
v_b = k_b C_R(0,t) = \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\end{dmath}
\label{eq14}
\end{dgroup}
2Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz

3Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
\begin{equation}
v_f = k_f C_O(0,t) = \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_b = k_b C_R(0,t) = \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\label{eq14b}
\end{equation}
4Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz


5Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
\begin{equation}
v_f = k_f C_O(0,t) = \frac{i_c}{nFA}
\end{equation}
6Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz
\begin{equation}
v_b = k_b C_R(0,t) = \frac{i_a}{nFA}
\label{eq14c}
\end{equation}
7Abc def ghi jkl mno pqr stu vwx yz

\end{document}
```